# hoverLeaveEvent() in Qt QGraphicsItem not always called

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, graphics, qgraphicsitem

I'm having a bit of an issue with a Qt QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItems, and hoverLeaveEvent().

On a hoverEnterEvent() I'm drawing a new graphic to the scene that I want to be removed on hoverLeaveEvent(), however if the user hovers the graphicsitem and then scrolls off of it instead of moving their mouse off of the item hoverLeaveEvent() is never called and the new graphic remains permanently on the scene.

I didn't see any way to capture scroll events from within my custom QGraphicsItem, so I wasn't sure of the best way to work around this.

I figured I could attach a timer to the new graphic, but then how would I know if the mouse is still hovering the QGraphicsItem that made it draw in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a Qt bug. Please report. Test case forthcoming.

Comment: If it was a bug, how long would it take to fix?

Comment: I have no idea. I should be able to add a test case code to my answer later today.